# Validation with parsley.js for radio and checkbox icheck js

Tags: jquery, parsley.js

I am trying to validation for Radio and Checkbox.

They are icheck JS.

The validation I want to perform is to require that a value is supplied for **Gender**.

My code is

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Gender</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
       <label class="radio-inline">
       <input type="radio" id="rdoMale" name="rdogender" class="icheck"
               value="Male" data-parsley-group="grpSignUp">Male</label>
       <label class="radio-inline">
       <input type="radio" id="rdoFemale" name="rdogender" class="icheck"
               value="Female" data-parsley-group="grpSignUp">Female</label>
</div>
```

On Submit Click Code :

```
$('#form1').parsley().validate("grpSignUp");
  if ($('#form1').parsley().isValid("grpSignUp")) {
    alert('Success');
  }
});
```

Comment: I am unclear what your question is

Comment: I want to Gender select is mandatory.

Comment: Use the `force: true` option?

Answer (score 0):

Add `data-parsley-multiple="gender"` to each input.